# Cannot update status field of the custom resource

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources, operator-sdk

I'm building a GO-based operator using Operator-sdk to manage my custom resource called `Module` which owns a deployment. My `_types.go` looks like this:

```
//+kubebuilder:object:root=true
//+kubebuilder:subresource:status
//+kubebuilder:subresource:scale:specpath=.spec.workerSettings.replicas,statuspath=.status.replicas,selectorpath=.status.selector
//+kubebuilder:printcolumn:name="Replicas",type="integer",JSONPath=".spec.workerSettings.replicas",description="The number of pods for this Module"
//+kubebuilder:printcolumn:name="Ready",type="integer",JSONPath=".status.readyReplicas",description="The number of ready pods for this Module"
//+kubebuilder:resource:shortName=mod;mods

// Module is the Schema for the Module API
type Module struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`

    Spec   ModuleSpec   `json:"spec,omitempty"`
    Status ModuleStatus `json:"status,omitempty"`
}

// ModuleStatus defines the observed state of Module
type ModuleStatus struct {
    Replicas      int32              `json:"replicas"`
    ReadyReplicas int32              `json:"readyReplicas"`
    Selector      string             `json:"selector"`
    Conditions    []metav1.Condition `json:"conditions"`
}
```

In reconcile I'm trying to set value of the `ReadyReplicas` field of my CR, which corresponds to the similar field of the deployment my custom resource (`Module`) owns.

```
func (r *ModuleReconciler) Reconcile(ctx context.Context, req ctrl.Request) (ctrl.Result, error) {
    var mod modulev1.Module
    err := r.Get(ctx, req.NamespacedName, &mod)
    if errors.IsNotFound(err) {
        return ctrl.Result{}, nil
    } else if err != nil {
        return ctrl.Result{Requeue: true}, err
    }

    var deploy appsv1.Deployment
    if created, err := r.createDeployIfNotExists(ctx, &deploy, &mod); err != nil {
        return ctrl.Result{}, err
    } else if created {
        return ctrl.Result{Requeue: true}, nil
    }

    ...
   
    // trying to set status the CR
    mod.Status.ReadyReplicas = deploy.Status.ReadyReplicas
    if r.Client.Status().Update(ctx, &mod); err != nil {
        log.Error(err, "failed to update Module status")
        return ctrl.Result{}, err
    }

    return ctrl.Result{}, nil
```

But nothing changes.. `r.Client.Status().Update(ctx, &mod)` performs silently, without any error, but the same costume resource instance comes back to the reconcile with default values of the all status fields.

```
v1alpha1.ModuleStatus {Replicas: 0, ReadyReplicas: 0, Selector: "", Conditions: []k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1.Condition len: 0, cap: 0, nil}
```

I checked how the manifest of custom resource looks "on the cluster" and it has no status section at all. Wherein it seems to be generated properly in my CRD:

[image: CRD generated by running "make manifest" command]

Please, help me figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: *"`r.Client.Status().Update(ctx, &mod)` performs silently, without any error"* -- How would you know? It's not like you're checking **its** error return value, at least not in the example code. It's true that you are checking *some* error, but that's not the one returned by `Update`.

Comment: @mkopriva not sure, that I understand.. What precisely should I check?

Comment: The expression in your example looks like this `if update(); err != nil {` but the correct way to "capture" the error return value and check it is `if err := update(); err != nil {`. You are basically ignoring the error returned by `Update` and you are checking an error variable created by a previous separate statement, the one returned by `r.Get`.

Comment: @mkopriva.. oh sh.. :D inattention. Error message is  `"Module.module.dev.module \"test-module\" is invalid: status.conditions: Required value"`

Comment: @mkopriva perhaps I able to figure out how to fix. Thank you for your comment, just needed someone to take a fresh look on the code

Comment: No worries, and good luck (I'd help further if I knew k8s but I don't :f).